# Deduplicate array in javascript based on id value in array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, duplicate-management, filters, array

I have a array which is a collection of 2 arrays which has duplicate Id records how do I deduplicate these in javascript. Filter is my primary array to which I add opleidingfilter. Filter array ends up with duplicate Id's

```
 Array.prototype.push.apply(filter,opleidingfilter);
```

I tried

```
var unique = [...new Set(filter.map(item => item[Id]))];
```

Where I end up with: Id is not defined

Here is an output of the array:

```
[{"Id":"a049E000004AKzSQAW","Name":"OPL-00000001","Categorie__c":"Techniek","Startdatum__c":"2017-12-04"},
{"Id":"a049E000002wymHQAQ","Name":"T010 Tennisleraar KSS Niveau 3","Categorie__c":"Fysiek","Startdatum__c":"2018-01-01"},
{"Id":"a049E000004AKyUQAW","Name":"OPL-00000000","Categorie__c":"Fysiek","Startdatum__c":"2018-09-01"},
{"Id":"a049E000002wymHQAQ","Name":"T010 Tennisleraar KSS Niveau 3","Categorie__c":"Fysiek","Startdatum__c":"2018-01-01"},
{"Id":"a049E000004AKzSQAW","Name":"OPL-00000001","Categorie__c":"Techniek","Startdatum__c":"2017-12-04"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found this working for me

```
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
            var newArray = [];
            var lookupObject  = {};
            for(var i in originalArray) {
                lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
            }

            for(i in lookupObject) {
                newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
            }
            return newArray;
        }
        var uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(filter, "Id");
```

Comment: Spot on - that'd be one way if you want to keep it vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the duplicate items in `opleidingfilter` before adding it to `filter`:

```
var filter = [1, 2, 3];
var opleidingfilter = [3, 4, 5, 6];
var joinedArray = filter.concat(opleidingfilter.filter(function (item) {
    return filter.indexOf(item) < 0;
}));
```

**Update:**

If you're dealing with arrays of objects, then a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [lodash](https://lodash.com) (or similar) is probably the easiest way to deal with these transformations. I mean you can write a pure JS function for it, though these libraries offer many other things that you can make a use of.

An example of how you would solve your problem if you were to use the `_.uniq` helper from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

`var uniqueArray = _.uniq(yourArrayWithDuplicates, function(o){ return o.Id; });`

Comment: My array has more fields filter=[1:a,2:b,3:c], opleidingfilter = [3:c, 4:d, 5:e, 6:f];  So if I would like to deduplicate on c would this be var joinedArray = filter.concat(opleidingfilter.filter(function (item[3]) {
    return filter.indexOf(item[3]) < 0;   ????
}));

Comment: Easiest is to use a library like underscore or lodash... On mobile now, can provide a proper answer later